# what are the diffrences between <address>.call and <address>.<function name>?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, evm

```
 contract GatekeeperOne {

  address public entrant;

  modifier gateOne() {
    require(msg.sender != tx.origin);
    _;
  }

  modifier gateTwo() {
    require(msg.gas % 8191 == 0);
    _;
  }

  modifier gateThree(bytes8 _gateKey) {
    require(uint32(_gateKey) == uint16(_gateKey));
    require(uint32(_gateKey) != uint64(_gateKey));
    require(uint32(_gateKey) == uint16(tx.origin));
    _;
  }

  function enter(bytes8 _gateKey) public gateOne gateTwo gateThree(_gateKey) returns (bool) {
    entrant = tx.origin;
    return true;
  }
}


contract test{
GatekeeperOne public t;
function test()public payable{
    t = GatekeeperOne(0x5c3c1540dfcd795b0aca58a496e3c30fe2405b07);

}
function attack()public payable{
    t.call.gas(41171)(bytes4(keccak256("good(bytes8)")), 0x123);
}
function attack2()public payable{
    t.enter(0x123);
}
function()public payable{}

}
```

when I execute the **attack()** it will be sucessful. And **attack2()** will fail.
the error message:

transact to `test.attack2` errored:

> VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the
>   initial state. Note: The constructor should be payable if you send
>   value.    Debug the transaction to get more information.

Comment: One calls a function called `good` and the other calls a function called `enter`... I'm not sure why they would do the same thing at all.

Answer (score 3):

As already said by smarx you are calling two different functions, therefore they behave differently.

About the question in the title:

You can get insight into the difference between `<address>.call` and `<address>.<function>` from the [documentation of Solidity](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/solidity/develop/solidity.pdf), in Section 4.4.4 (page 68) and in Section 4.4.5 (pages 70-71), respectively.

### `<address>.call`

> `<address>.call(bytes memory) returns (bool)`: issue low-level CALL with the given payload, returns false on failure, forwards all available gas, adjustable

### `<address>.function`

> Function calls cause exceptions if the called contract does not exist (in the sense that the account does not contain
> code) or if the called contract itself throws an exception or goes out of gas

### Conclusion

So the former is low-level in the sense that you have to check the return value manually, while the second let the exception bubble up (is more high-level).